# ATOM-128 string encryption/decryption (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, encryption

I am trying to make an Android app that encrypts any given string in ATOM-128
example : input "hello" / output "MIH3+/CC+qCC"
I already tried it with c# (windows desktop app) and it's working well when I tried to do the same thing with java in android studio I have this results :
input "hello"
outut "2662144270646427486464"

THIS IS THE CODE

```
public class ATOM {
public static String Encrypt(String clearText)
{
    String key = "/128GhIoPQROSTeUbADfgHijKLM+n0pFWXY456xyzB7=39VaqrstJklmNuZvwcdEC";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int i = 0;
    int[] indexes = new int[4];
    int[] chars = new int[3];
    do
    {
        chars[0] = i + 1 > clearText.length() ? 0 : (int)clearText.toCharArray()[i++];
        chars[1] = i + 2 > clearText.length() ? 0 : (int)clearText.toCharArray()[i++];
        chars[2] = i + 3 > clearText.length() ? 0 : (int)clearText.toCharArray()[i++];
        indexes[0] = chars[0] >> 2;
        indexes[1] = ((chars[0] & 3) << 4) | (chars[1] >> 4);
        indexes[2] = ((chars[1] & 15) << 2) | (chars[2] >> 6);
        indexes[3] = chars[2] & 63;
        if ((char)chars[1] == 0)
        {
            indexes[2] = 64;
            indexes[3] = 64;
        }
        else if ((char)chars[2] == 0)
        {
            indexes[3] = 64;
        }

        for (int index : indexes)
        {
            result.append(index);
        }
    }
    while (i < clearText.length());
    return result.toString();
}
public static String Decrypt(String clearText)
{
    String key = "/128GhIoPQROSTeUbADfgHijKLM+n0pFWXY456xyzB7=39VaqrstJklmNuZvwcdEC";
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int[] indexes = new int[4];
    int[] chars = new int[3];
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        indexes[0] = key.indexOf(i++);
        indexes[1] = key.indexOf(i++);
        indexes[2] = key.indexOf(i++);
        indexes[3] = key.indexOf(i++);
        chars[0] = (indexes[0] << 2) | (indexes[1] >> 4);
        chars[1] = (indexes[1] & 15) << 4 | (indexes[2] >> 2);
        chars[2] = (indexes[2] & 3) << 6 | indexes[3];
        result.append((char)chars[0]);
        if (indexes[2] != 64)
            result.append((char)chars[1]);
        if (indexes[3] != 64)
            result.append((char)chars[2]);
    }
    while (i < clearText.length());
    return result.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: It seems that ATOM-128 is an **encoding** similar to Base64, **not encryption**. BTW, can you provide a link to ATOM-128 specification?

Comment: sorry I can't find any link that describes the ATOM-128 specs

Comment: sorry I can't find any link that describes the ATOM-128 specs, and I tried the answer given below and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the StringBuilder doc :

```
public StringBuilder append (int i)

Appends the string representation of the specified int value. 
The int value is converted to a string according to the rule defined by valueOf(int).
```

So everytime you call

```
result.append(index);
```

You append the string representation of the actual number. What you need to do first is to parse your int into, I guess, the char ASCII representation.

```
result.append(((char)index));
```

should do it.

Link to doc :
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append(int)

Comment: close but still not correct, now for the same string (hello) I get "   ,@@ 0@@"